# How do I install selectorlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x

ImportError: No module named selectorlib

Comment: What is the point of this question as you already know the (trivial) answer?

Comment: Couldn't find this question here before and i found it from other sources. Now the users can get it from here itself. @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install selectorlib
```

for python3,

```
pip3 install selectorlib
```

> Documentation to [install Selectorlib](https://selectorlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)